# Selecting postgresql date interval from database

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database which contains start dates and durations in a json object. I need to calculate the end date using this information. I have tried the following request:

```
SELECT 
    content->>'duration' AS duration, 
    (content->>'start_date')::DATE AS start, 
    (content->>'start_date')::DATE + interval content->>'duration' AS end
FROM table
WHERE some_condition;
```

This give a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "content"
LINE 4:         (content->>'start_date')::DATE + interval content->>...
```

The interval returned from json will be something like `'1 month'` or `'8 weeks'`

Comment: What exactly is stored in the `duration` column?

Comment: See edit, sorry should have clarified

Comment: try `(content->>'duration')::interval`

Comment: That works, thank you.